# NSCache() is not working properly

Tags: macos

I think I am tired of `NSCache()`. Could not understand what's the problem behind this. Trying to save an array of `[AnyObject]` to `NSCahce()`, which I have done using this following line of code.

```
NSCache().setObject(data, forKey: "News")
```

And tried to get it back using this way.

```
     if let news = NSCache()("News") as? [AnyObject]
     {
     }
     else 
     {
       // I am always here :)
     }
```

So I was thinking what's the problem with this. After searching a bit in Google I could see that setting `totalCostLimit` and `countLimit` will help you solve this problem. So I have set it like this.

```
NSCache().totalCostLimit = 50000
NSCache().countLimit = 50000
```

After setting this also, it was not working. So I thought of running this code in main thread, which I have done like this.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          NSCache().setObject(data, forKey: "News")
        }
```

Still it returned `nil`. Now last but not the least I have created one global instance of NSCache() and called all these operations using that instance. Well, doing like that also didn't give the expected result. It always gave me `nil`.

What's happening here? I know that `NSCache()` can store `AnyObject` values. I am saving lot of images in the same project without any problem, when I am trying to save this it returns `nil`.

Well this `AnyObject` contains some custom classes. Is that can be a problem? If yes, how will I save it locally without using `CoreData` or `NSUserdefaults`.

How I created an instance globally and accessed these. Created one instance of NSCache in the AppDelegate.swift file but outside of AppDelegate class

```
 let mainCache = NSCache()

    @NSApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

      func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
      {
        mainCache.totalCostLimit = 50000
        mainCache.countLimit = 50000
      }
    }
```

Later I have used it like this.

```
mainCache.setObject(data, forKey: "News")
```

And getting the data back like this.

```
 if let news = mainCache.objectForKey("News") as? [AnyObject]
 {

 }
else
 {
         // Always here :)           
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't that just create temporary `NSCache` instances and then immediately destroy them?  Use an instance variable, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

When you write `NSCache()` you are **creating a new NSCache instance**. You're doing this on just about every line.

What you need to do is create one instance, `let myCache = NSCache()`, and then reuse it: `myCache.setObject(data, forKey: "News")`.

Comment: I have created one global instance and tried, But it was not working

Comment: Is the NSCache data will be removed when I run the Mac app each time?

Comment: Updated question, Please check.

Comment: Looks like that I have to use CoreData.